# How to add text to specific fields in a website that I take from a csv

Tags: csv, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide, selenium-chromedriver

Sorry if the title is not clear, I had hard time writing a short title that will explain this so here is what I need.

I have a website and in this website there is a form that want to fill its fields with the content of a csv I have.

So lets say there is a csv with titles:

```
id    name   age

3    john    35
```

and in my websites I have a form like:

```
person:

id _____

name _____

age _____
```

So now I want to fill this form with selenium automatically and have the selenium take the data from the csv....how can I do this?

Comment: Do you have practice with selenium? Or you are new?

Answer (score 0):

There is a method called sendKeys(), use that method to fill the form.

for example:

```
driver.findElement(xpath_for_id).sendKeys("3");
driver.findElement(xpath_for_name).sendKeys("John");
driver.findElement(xpath_for_age).sendKeys("35");
```

Answer (score 0):

For my part I use a home made function which returns an array of object

```
public static Object[][] getCsvData(String testDataFilePath){
...

}
```

this will be used in a DataProvider

```
   @DataProvider(name = "dataSet")
   public Object[][] provideData() throws IOException {
      return getCsvData("testdata/xxx.csv");
   }
```

To use like this to test multiple combinations 
each line of the csv will be a set (id, name, age)

```
   @Test(dataProvider = "dataSet")
   public void testForm(String id, String name, String age) {

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("yourXpath")).sendKeys(id);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("yourXpath")).sendKeys(name);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("yourXpath")).sendKeys(age);

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class CSVReaderUtil {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        CSVReader csvRead = new CSVReader(new FileReader("F:\\csvfiledata.csv"));
        String[] row = null;

        try {
            while((data = csvRead.readNext()) != null){
            driver.findElement(By.id("id")).sendKeys(data[0]);
            driver.findElement(By.id("name")).sendKeys(data[1]);
            driver.findElement(By.id("age")).sendKeys(data[2]);
            }
        }catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

csv file contents:
3,john,35
2,jeb,40
```